# how to add a complete custom row in wordpress post table at end

Tags: wordpress, post, admin

I want to add a custom row at end of WordPress post table, having some calculations from the above data like e.g  average of student marks or sum of all marks.

[image]

Comment: Have you ever test ACF custom fields?

Comment: Please see the screen shot. 
Acf can do this?